# Calculate distances from points to all adjacent polygons in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, proximity

I have the zip code centroids and state polygons. I want to calculate the distances from each zip code centroid to all the nearby states using ArcGIS. I have tried to use Generate Near table tool, but I get the distance to the all states instead of just nearby ones.

How I can do that?'

Comment: Sounds like you need to read the [help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm#GUID-A0E26B41-0266-4DF9-8BA6-6A2062F9A1C1) file, have you experimented with the _Find only closest feature_ parameter yet?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: If I check "Find only closest feaure" I will get just the closest distance. I need distances to all adjacent polygons. I am using ArcMap 10.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter Generate Near table:

[image]

By Polygon Neighbours:

[image]

So create and populate highlighted field in both tables. And join first one to second using that field. Values in NEAR_DIST are your answers:

[image]

Note that only point/polygon 2 has 4 neighbours, others have less:

[image]